# Is there a professional way to plan your REST API?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am planning out a Skill marketplace, I am using Python Django REST API, I want to know if there's a professional way to design a API to be consumed by multiple frontend.

This is my first time of designing an API (though I have done multiple small projects).

Any links, guide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are two different question in one. What exactly you want to work? Frontend or backend? If you have endpoints ready there are no blocks to stop you to be used by multiple frontends. Nevertheless, you'll need to implement queues to deal with multiple requests. If you want to know how I design backend using DJango and DRF only let me know.

Comment: Thanks @Elias for responding. I'm working on backend, and there are no ready endpoints. I am to design them. I would love to learn how you design your backend using Django and DRF.

Answer (score 0):

I am designing e-commerce REST APIs using Django REST. Below are the steps that I have followed in designing.

1. Go through the Django REST tutorial and understand the basic blocks of the REST framework.
2. Before designing models and jumping to code have proper knowledge of the requirement.
3. Learn how to override create and update method of serializers because as the project grows, you may get a requirement to override those methods.
4. Implement permission classes for all the views.
5. Implement, get_object, get_serializer_class, get_query_set in views, that provides an opportunity for customizing your results.
6. Handling errors should be done efficiently with meaningful messages for the end-user.